# Print an array in tester class

Tags: java

I am trying to return the array of students in a tester class for the Course class but I keep getting a .class expected error. I've tried to do
`students[].TestCourse` but that doesn't work either.

```
public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private String[] students = new String[4];
    private int numberOfStudents;
  
    public Course(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
  
    public void addStudent(String student) {
        if (numberOfStudents == students.length) {
            String [] copy = new String [students.length*2];
            System.arraycopy(students,0,copy,0,students.length);
            students = copy;
        }
        
        students[numberOfStudents] = student;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }
 
    public String[] getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
 
    public void dropStudent(String student) {
        for (int i=0;i<students.length;i++) {
            if (students[i]==student) {
                students[i] = null;
            }
            for (i=i;i<students.length-1;i++) {
                students[i] = students[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TestCourse {
    public static void main() {
        Course compScience = new Course("Computer Science");
        compScience.addStudent("Jack");
        compScience.addStudent("Dean");
        compScience.addStudent("Leon");
        compScience.dropStudent("Dean");
        System.out.println("The students currently in this course are "+ students[]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line in your `main` method to:

```java
System.out.println("The students currently in this course are "+ Arrays.toString(compScience.getStudents()));
```

and it should fire up!

All you've done is try to call the field of a class directly when you need to access it via the reference you created  `Course compScience = new Course("Computer Science");` ... then call it's method `getStudents()` as follows `compScience.getStudents()`. To get the contents of the array you then need to wrap this method call in `Arrays.toString()` as above.

Comment: you can create any methods you like. You're the judge/jury/executioner!

Comment: When I run that I get "The students currently in this course are [Ljava.lang.String;@56755e13"

Comment: Wrap in `Arrays.toString(compScience.getStudents())` to print the elements.